# How do I setup a router to forward packets (to/from) a specific IP to a specific _hardware port_?

Tags: router, ip, route

I would like to route all traffic to 192.168.1.10 to hardware port 1 on my router and all traffic to 192.168.1.11 to hardware port 2 on my router. The issue here is that I have a network attached device (192.168.1.10) that claims to have the fastest route to the other device (192.168.1.11). However, the link between devices is broken, and the packets to 192.168.1.11 are lost.

I'd like to explicitly associate IP addresses with the hardware port (1-4) on my router. Is this possible? If so, what feature should I look for in the settings page or in the specification for a new router?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a home router, in which case the 4 ports are a switch and you don't need to (and can't) configure anything to tell the router what IP is on which port.  Other than that, it's totally unclear what's going on: It sounds like your "network attached device" is misconfigured, but w/out knowing what the device is and knowing where the packets that are being lost are coming from, it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

With a router you can give each port an IP.  However, it doesn't matter what the router thinks, because if a device feels it should send packet somewhere on the LAN, it going to do that, and it will never arrive at the router. If both the NAS device and the device with the other IP have the same subnet, and you are using a strandard L2 switch, it will use that (which is probably what you want).

So somehow you need to tell the device not to use that route instead of trying to tell the  router. A work around might be to change the the subnet on the device to something that does not include the other IP, this will force it to use the router (the device's default gateway) for ip traffic. [Here is a nice  post](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/serverfault-wiki-how-does-subnetting-work) about subnetting from Evan.

I also think you need to explain this a bit more, I am not sure I have an accurate picture.  But I would focus on fixing the NAS device, pushing all your storage traffic through a router is probably not the best idea.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Here's a little more about the configuration. I've got a PC that exchanges data over Ethernet with two devices. The current configuration uses two NICs and sends the traffic to device 1 over NIC 1 and traffic to device 2 over NIC 2. Is there a way to get this behavior from a router so that we can use a single NIC?

Comment: You probably want to use a switch, not a router.  Assuming the network is 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0.  And router is 192.168.1.1 with that subnet.  Device A as is 192.168.1.2 and Device  B is 192.168.1.3 (both with 255.255.255.0 subet).  Just plug both devices and your router into the switch and disable the second nick on the device with two nics.  Both devices will talk to each other via the switch, and the internet via the switch -- > router --> internet.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to route all traffic to 192.168.1.10 to hardware port 1 on my router and all traffic to 192.168.1.11 to hardware port 2 on my router.

That would be possible on a managed switch/hub, but not on an unmanaged hub/switch.  Routing network traffic is done to the IP, not the hardware.  The benefit being that you could move the cable from your switch/hub's port from 2 to 3 to 8/etc and traffic will always get to the correct host on the network.

If traffic is not moving between the hosts at IPs 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.11, it's possible you have a bad port and/or cable(s) but you really need to diagnose the issue to know the true reason before I'd suggest looking at new hardware.

Comment: Another possibility is if you are trying to connect NIC to NIC you need a crossover cable.